# Logstash matching ceph client and server separation

Tags: logging, logstash, ceph, grok

So I have a fresh logstash install and I am trying to deploy logstash to get a handle on the logs.

I am going through and will eventually segment the logstash filters based on subsystem and currently I am working on parsing osd logs.

Here is a sample line I am working with:

```
2015-06-02 16:45:49.515277 7f4968cfe700  0 -- 10.16.64.68:6813/97613 >> 10.16.64.29:6805/35260 pipe(0x25e36500 sd=538 :6813 s=2 pgs=15426 cs=623 l=0 c=0x1586fa20).fault with nothing to send, going to standby
```

My filter currently looks like this:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date} %{BASE16FLOAT:osd_epoch}  %{NUMBER:error_bool} -- %{CEPH_HOST:client_A} %{FROMTO} %{CEPH_HOST:client_B}
```

Where ${CEPH_HOST} and ${FROMTO} are just short patterns ::

```
FROMTO (?:[<|>]){1,2}
CEPH_HOST (%{IPORHOST:ip}\:%{POSINT:port}/%{POSINT:socket})
```

The issue is that IP now seems to house two addresses.

```
  "client_A": [
[
  "10.16.64.68:6813/97613"
]
],
"ip": [
[
  "10.16.64.68",
  "10.16.64.29"
]
],
"HOSTNAME": [
[
  "10.16.64.68",
  "10.16.64.29"
```

I would like to grok it so that `client_a` has an IP and `client_b` has an IP.

However, does it matter in the end?

Can I leave it as is?

If so, will I be able to sort it later? If not, how do I segment it so that `client_a` and `client_b` are separated?

Do I need to create a "unique" pattern for both?

Comment: Based on that JSON output, your grok filter isn't working 100% since it seems to be missing some fields. That, or you've clipped it for brevity. If it's the latter, can you please post the whole thing? It will make things easier.

Comment: It was clipped for brevity. I am still making it but for now l just use %{GREEDYDATA} on the end. I am rather new to log stash, may I ask why this would be easier or if there is any other data I can provide to help. 

Thanks GregL!

Comment: I ask for more details because there might be things affecting the filter and output than are initially evident. The whole grok filter, as well as the whole resulting event would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you ever worked out how to do this, but I was looking at something for my own environment that's similar and I think the only way to do it is to setup patterns for each client.

I've tested them both in the [grok constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/) and they return valid fields.

If you just wanted to have a field for Client A (10.16.64.68:6813/97613) and Client B (10.16.64.29:6805/35260), this would work:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date} %{BASE16FLOAT:osd_epoch}  %{NUMBER:error_bool} -- (?<client_a>(%{IPORHOST}\:%{POSINT}/%{POSINT})) %{FROMTO} (?<client_b>(%{IPORHOST}\:%{POSINT}/%{POSINT}))
```

> 2015-06-02 16:45:49.515277 7f4968cfe700 0 -- 10.16.64.68:6813/97613 10.16.64.29:6805/35260
>       **MATCHED**
>         client_a: 10.16.64.68:6813/97613
>         client_b: 10.16.64.29:6805/35260
>         error_bool: 0
>         date: 2015-06-02·16:45:49.515277
>         osd_epoch: 7f4968cfe700

If you also wanted individual fields for each element of that connection (client a/b IP, client a/b port, client a/b socket) this pattern should work:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date} %{BASE16FLOAT:osd_epoch}  %{NUMBER:error_bool} -- (?<client_a>(%{IPORHOST:client_a_ip}\:%{POSINT:client_a_port}/%{POSINT:client_a_socket})) %{FROMTO} (?<client_b>(%{IPORHOST:client_b_ip}\:%{POSINT:client_b_port}/%{POSINT:client_b_socket}))
```

> 2015-06-02 16:45:49.515277 7f4968cfe700 0 -- 10.16.64.68:6813/97613 10.16.64.29:6805/35260
>       **MATCHED**
>         client_a: 10.16.64.68:6813/97613
>         client_b: 10.16.64.29:6805/35260
>         client_a_ip: 10.16.64.68
>         client_b_ip: 10.16.64.29
>         client_a_port: 6813
>         client_b_port: 6805
>         client_a_socket: 97613
>         client_b_socket: 35260
>         error_bool: 0
>         date: 2015-06-02·16:45:49.515277
>         osd_epoch: 7f4968cfe700

Comment: Thanks Greg!!! 

That looks like exactly what I needed! is <client_b> just a group label?